# How to enable a button only when text_field is not empty

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a RoR app. I want to keep the search btton disable until something is entered in the search box.

I tried the following:

```
<%if Voylla::Application.config.search_swiftype_enabled %>
<form>
<input type="text" id="st-search-input" class="st-search-input" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Swiftype = window.Swiftype || {};
  (function() {
    Swiftype.key = 'Lefxmsx2p9qdqxmxxqSR';
    Swiftype.inputElement = '#st-search-input';
    Swiftype.resultContainingElement = '#st-results-container';
    Swiftype.attachElement = '#st-search-input';
    Swiftype.renderStyle = "inline";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = "//swiftype.com/embed.js";
    var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
  }());
</script>
<%elsif Voylla::Application.config.google_custom_search_enabled %>
  <div id='search-box'>
  <%= form_tag "/search", :method => :get, :id => "search-form" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], {:id => "search-text", :placeholder => "SEARCH FOR PRODUCTS"} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#text_field').val() ==  "")
      $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#text_field').keyup(function(){
        if($('#text_field').val() !=  "")
          $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', false);
        else
          $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);
      });
});
</script>
    <%end%>
  </div>
<%else%>
  <%= form_tag products_url, :method => :get do  %>
    <%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords], {:id => "productSearch", :placeholder => "Search"} %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

But the search button is always enabled, even when the search box is empty

EDIT: code from browser:

```
<div id="search-box">
<form></form>
<input id="search-text" name="q" placeholder="SEARCH FOR PRODUCTS" type="text" value>
<input name="Commit" type="submit" value="Go">
<script>
$('#search-text').on('keydown keyup change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $('#submitButtonId').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
<script>
```

Comment: Can you please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#search-text').on('keydown keyup change', function(){
    var $submit = $(this).nextAll('input[type="submit"]:eq(0)');
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Here is a fiddle so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/merrifield69/hAHHZ/

Comment: I tried this. Replaced, `text_field` byt `text_field_tag`, but it didn't work as expected. The button is still enabled

Comment: Then something must be wrong with your html. Can you please post you generated html so I can see what the issue might be? Also, please make sure that the ID `submitButtonId` is *only* being used once on that page.

Comment: Your problem is that you submit button has no `ID`

Comment: I just noticed this. Working on it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked, but the button is not blurred. It appears the same, though its not clickable

Comment: @nish Just add `input:disabled{opacity:.5}` into your css file(you can make it look however you want it doesn't ahve to just be opacity.)

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text_field"/>
<button type="submit" id="submitButtonId">Submit</button>
```

Script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if($('#text_field').val() == "")
      $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#text_field').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "")
          $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', false);
        else
          $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);
      });
   });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5r/1/)

Comment: My html is totally different, So I am unable to apply this. Would using `#text_field_tag` in place of #text work??

Comment: you can use #text_field